# Empty resultset on BINARY comparison though java.sql.PreparedStatement.setBytes

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, percona, connector-j

I have Percona Mysql server and Java client with custom ORM. In DB I have table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `PlayerSecret` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `secret` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `player_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `PlayerSecret_secret_unique` (`secret`),
  KEY `PlayerSecret_player_id` (`player_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=141 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I found that query `SELECT PlayerSecret.player_id FROM PlayerSecret WHERE PlayerSecret.secret = ?`
returns an empty resultset when parameter is provided by `java.sql.PreparedStatement#setBytes` method, and works as expected though  `java.sql.PreparedStatement#setBinaryStream`. I've enabled mysql general log and found that in this log both queries are the same, I've checked this in hex mode.

In general log it looks like:

```
SELECT PlayerSecret.player_id FROM PlayerSecret WHERE PlayerSecret.secret = '<96>R\Ø8üõA\í¤Z´^E\Ô\ÊÁ\Ö'
```

Query parameter from general log in hex mode:
`2796 525c d838 fcf5 415c eda4 5ab4 055c d45c cac1 5cd6 27`

Value in database:

```
mysql> select hex(secret) from PlayerSecret where id=109;
+----------------------------------+
| hex(secret)                      |
+----------------------------------+
| 9652D838FCF541EDA45AB405D4CAC1D6 |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The problem is that my ORM doing this query though `setBytes` method, I think it is right way for `BINARY` data type, but it doesn't work.

Part of `my.cnf` with encoding settings(maybe it's matters):

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
general_log = on
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysqld_general.log
require_secure_transport = ON
init-connect = SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Java code:

```
var uuid = UUID.fromString("9652d838-fcf5-41ed-a45a-b405d4cac1d6");
var array = ByteBuffer.allocate(16).putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits()).putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits()).array();
// works
stmt.setBinaryStream(index, new ByteArrayInputStream(array));
// don't works
stmt.setBytes(index, array);
```

I can't understand what is the difference between both cases, and how to fix this for `setBytes` variant.
Maybe someone can clarify this or point me to important parts/places?

My env:

- Openjdk 11
- HicariCP 3.1.0
- MySQL Connector/J 8.0.13
- Percona 5.7.24-26-log Percona Server (GPL), Release '26', Revision 'c8fe767'

Comment: Show the code where you use `setBytes` and `setBinaryStream`. We don't know where you get the bytes and how you manipulate them.

Comment: @RealSkeptic added, but since both queries is the same in general log - does it mean that difference should be in query metadata or any other place?

Comment: You may have hidden characters in your general log. What I can see is that the hex from the general log does not match the hex from the database. Best provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, I've also find this - it contains backslashes escaping for some bytes, and I think it's strange for binary data(maybe escaping occurs on writing to general log)...but it works with them, I don't know where should I search reason of such behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've figured it out. The problem was in `character_set_client=utf8` instead of `utf8mb4`.
This query shows the difference between expected values and real thread values(think it's very handy query):

```sql
SELECT VARIABLE_NAME, gv.VARIABLE_VALUE 'Global', tv.VARIABLE_VALUE 'Thread value', THREAD_ID, PROCESSLIST_ID 
FROM performance_schema.global_variables gv   
  JOIN performance_schema.variables_by_thread tv USING (VARIABLE_NAME) 
  JOIN performance_schema.threads USING(THREAD_ID) 
WHERE gv.VARIABLE_VALUE <> tv.VARIABLE_VALUE ;

+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+----------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME         | Global             | Thread value       | THREAD_ID | PROCESSLIST_ID |
+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+----------------+
| autocommit            | ON                 | OFF                |        82 |             56 |
| character_set_client  | utf8mb4            | utf8               |        82 |             56 |
| character_set_results | utf8mb4            |                    |        82 |             56 |
```

When I replaced `init-connect = SET collation_connection = utf8mb4_unicode_ci` with `init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci'` in `my.cnf` the problem disappeared and queries though `setBytes` began to work as expected.

Why is it works for `setBinaryStream` and doesn't work for `setBytes` - 
because in first case works this code `com.mysql.cj.ServerPreparedQueryBindings#setBinaryStream(int, java.io.InputStream, int)`:

```
@Override
public void setBinaryStream(int parameterIndex, InputStream x, int length) {
    if (x == null) {
        setNull(parameterIndex);
    } else {
        ServerPreparedQueryBindValue binding = getBinding(parameterIndex, true);
        this.sendTypesToServer.compareAndSet(false, binding.resetToType(MysqlType.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB, this.numberOfExecutions));
        binding.value = x;
        binding.isLongData = true;
        binding.bindLength = this.useStreamLengthsInPrepStmts.getValue() ? length : -1;
    }
}
```

Important part here is `binding.resetToType(MysqlType.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB` - driver notes mysql that this data is `BLOB`

And in second case `com.mysql.cj.ServerPreparedQueryBindings#setBytes(int, byte[])` contains:

```
@Override
public void setBytes(int parameterIndex, byte[] x) {
    if (x == null) {
        setNull(parameterIndex);
    } else {
        ServerPreparedQueryBindValue binding = getBinding(parameterIndex, false);
        this.sendTypesToServer.compareAndSet(false, binding.resetToType(MysqlType.FIELD_TYPE_VAR_STRING, this.numberOfExecutions));
        binding.value = x;
    }
}
```

`MysqlType.FIELD_TYPE_VAR_STRING` means that this is not simple bytes, but string in some encoding(with some collation).
I really don't know why driver sets this type of data for bytes - this question stays opened for me.